# Client Side Application error for Robotics Simulation with swift-sim

Tags: python, simulation, robotics

```
import roboticstoolbox as rtb
import spatialmath as sm
import numpy as np
from swift import Swift


# Make and instance of the Swift simulator and open it
env = Swift()
env.launch(realtime=True)

# Make a panda model and set its joint angles to the ready joint configuration
panda = rtb.models.Panda()
panda.q = panda.qr

# Set a desired and effector pose an an offset from the current end-effector pose
Tep = panda.fkine(panda.q) * sm.SE3.Tx(0.2) * sm.SE3.Ty(0.2) * sm.SE3.Tz(0.45)

# Add the robot to the simulator
env.add(panda)

# Simulate the robot while it has not arrived at the goal
arrived = False
while not arrived:

    # Work out the required end-effector velocity to go towards the goal
    v, arrived = rtb.p_servo(panda.fkine(panda.q), Tep, 1)
    
    # Set the Panda's joint velocities
    panda.qd = np.linalg.pinv(panda.jacobe(panda.q)) @ v
    
    # Step the simulator by 50 milliseconds
    env.step(0.05)
```

Trying the introductory code for robot simulation using the swift sim library, when I run this code, my default browser (chrome) pops up and than I get the error:

`Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).`

I have checked the browser logs, and I am getting a lot of failed to load source warnings, a lot of this one:

```
index-0723cc3b940b78c7.js:194 Error: Could not load retrieve/C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\rtbdata\xacro\franka_description\meshes\visual\link0.dae: fetch for "http://localhost:52000/retrieve/C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Local/Packages/PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0/LocalCache/local-packages/Python311/site-packages/rtbdata/xacro/franka_description/meshes/visual/link0.dae" responded with 404: File not found)
at Object.onError (index-0723cc3b940b78c7.js:194:104816)
at index-0723cc3b940b78c7.js:186:224752
```

I've checked and the file that is being requested is in the provided directory. I have tried downloading the library again, but it has not helped.

I tried including env.hold, but it still produced the same error.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more work and research, I was able to come to a conclusion. Apparently, the issue is not on the user but on the library, as it incorrectly formats the Windows filepath. You only need to manually implement this fork using this link: [Link to the pull request](https://github.com/jhavl/swift/pull/52)